# Maximum six connections causing issues in browser on Kindle (Silk)

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, tcp, amazon-silk

Don't know if anyone can help here, but I will ask anyway.

We have a website built using ASP.NET (VB).  It works fine on the desktop, iPad or mobile phone browsers, but on a Kindle tablet (in Silk browser) frequently the maximum six tcp connections rears its ugly head and bombs out the website for a four-minute timeout period, and it happens mainly on .js and .css files.

I have read many references on Google and the like for how to potentially prevent by disabling cache etc, but has anyone got a known working solution to this issue?

The hosting of the website in IIS.

Comment: Can you post any more specifics about the error? Is it the client that cannot connect to the website? or is the website itself down for four minutes?

Comment: Thanks. It's not an error as such, but if the website is running in the Kindle and connected to Chrome on the PC over a USB cable for debugging remotely, then certain .js and .css files are flagged as "Stalled" and then after 4 minutes they time out, and the Kindle will load the web page usually without the CSS and/or .js files.  Have tried disabling cache in the masterpage of the asp.net website but it still appears to be caching.  Only affects Kindle browser.  All ok on desktop, ipad or android table or mobile phone browser.  Does that offer anymore insight?